# How to place figure or text before a paragraph?

Tags: floats

I need a way to display warnings (figure and text, exactly like the image attached) in a manual I'm creating. I'm trying to create an environment in order to replicate this behaviour easier in the entire document, but so far I coundn't replicate it. I read somewhere that I could use `longtable`, I tried this approach and a space was created before the next paragraph, which doesn't meet my needs for the document I have to make.

[image: Image or text before paragraph]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some possible ways to mark text with margin icons: (1) `\marginpar` command + `\fbox` command; (2) the powerful and complex `tcolorbox` package (has some dedicated "documentation text+icon" styles for exactly this purpose); (3) `bclogo` package, easier and quicker to use.

Comment: It sort of depends on where the page margin is.  In any case, you might wind up using `\noindent\llap{...}`